# Understanding zero vector through an example to find values of t and s

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezaLS.png]

I need to determine if the zero vector is in W. And I'm asked to find values for t & s such that: [image]

My natural intuition (which could be wrong) is to:

- add an additional column to fill out a matrix that is 4 rows
- Then place that rogue 2 of the second row in it's own column
- then set the vector out as:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & -3\\2 & 3 & 0 \\0 & 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and solve for the $\vec{v}$ values like so:

$0v_1+1s-3t=0$

$2v_1 + 3s+0t =0 \rightarrow s=\frac{-2}{3}v_1$

$0v_1+3s-1t=0$

$0v_1+3s + 0t=0$

Such that: $\vec{v} = s\begin{bmatrix} \frac{-2}{3}+1\\3\\3\\3 \end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix} -3\\0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

However, it seems I'm worng as the answer sheet says: "The zero vector is not in W. There is no t and s such that the vector equation is satisfied."

Where am I going wrong here, please help me identify my knowledge gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors in $W$ can be written as follows

$ w = t \begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + s \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\3\\3\\3\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Now we want to find $t , s$ such that $w = 0$, the augmented matrix of this linear system is

$\begin{bmatrix} -3 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 3 && -2 \\ 1 && 3 && 0 \\ 0 && 3 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

By looking the second and fourth rows, we can immediately see that the system is inconsistent (i.e. has no solution), because the second row says

$3 s = -2 $

while the fourth row says

$ 3 s = 0 $

Subtracting, we get $0 \cdot s = -2 $  which has no solution.

Therefore, the zero vector in not in the set $W$, i.e. $0 \notin W$

Comment: Thanks @grab a coffee, this was really good and helpful. Makes so much sense that if there are two solutions to S that it'd be "inconsistent". It then triggered back to me searching ou what "inconsistent" means in Linear Algebra (ie. no solutions, there for zero is not in set W).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your "natural intuition" is to do things in such a complicated way!  You have $\begin{bmatrix}s- 3t \\ 2+ 3s \\ 3s+ t \\ 3s\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ so you must have s- 3t= 0, 2+ 3S= 0, 3s+ t= 0, and 3s= 0.  From 3s= 0, s= 0 so the other three equations become s= 0, 2+ 3s= 0, and 3s= 0.  There is NO value of s that satisfies all of those.

(I wonder about the "2+ 3s" since that has no "t" in it.)

Comment: Yea what would we do with the 2 + 3s, seem to have threw me off too. but @grab a coffee answered it and did the same i did intuitively, just added a column to represent it without a scalar t or s in front of it. Thanks for your answer btw.